# Xcodeでコンパイル時、The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)　となる

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

シュミレーター実行しようとすると、出ます。
Mac本体再起動、シュミレーターリセットや再起動、Xcode再起動やクリーンを試しましたが、解決されません。
どうもコンパイルのエラーではないようです。
ネットで調べても解決策が分かりません。

わかる方、教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Xcode 6.2 watchkit sample app doesn't start. "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097067/xcode-6-2-watchkit-sample-app-doesnt-start-the-operation-couldn-t-be-complete) は参考になりませんか？

Comment: 上記のHPを参考にbundle identifierの確認をしてみました。キーボードエクステンションだったため、普通と違う命名でした。直し、動作しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントより

[Xcode 6.2 watchkit sample app doesn't start. "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097067/xcode-6-2-watchkit-sample-app-doesnt-start-the-operation-couldn-t-be-complete) を参考にbundle identifierの確認をしてみました。キーボードエクステンションだったため、普通と違う命名でした。直し、動作しました‌​。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit Extensionで同じ現象が出ました(xcode7.2)。
HostとWatch Extensionの、identifier Teamが異なっていました。
Extensionではidentifierを揃えないとダメなようです。